# How to start the pagination from right to left in Flutter car swiper?

Tags: flutter, pagination, swiper.js, card

Is it possible to make the pagination start from right to left?

```
child: Swiper(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final image = letterVowelsImages[index];
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          image,
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    indicatorLayout: PageIndicatorLayout.COLOR,
                    autoplay: false,
                    itemCount: letterVowelsImages.length,
                    pagination: const SwiperPagination(
                      builder: DotSwiperPaginationBuilder(
                        color: Colors.black38,
                        activeColor: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    control: const SwiperControl(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
```

..................................................

Answer (score 1):

```
child: Swiper(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final image = letterVowelsImages[index];
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
      child: Image.asset(
        image,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    );
  },
  indicatorLayout: PageIndicatorLayout.COLOR,
  autoplay: false,
  itemCount: letterVowelsImages.length,
  pagination: const SwiperPagination(
    builder: DotSwiperPaginationBuilder(
      color: Colors.black38,
      activeColor: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
  control: const SwiperControl(
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
),
```

Before this code snippet, add the following line to reverse the letterVowelsImages list:

```
letterVowelsImages = letterVowelsImages.reversed.toList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I have tried another method where I just made the index: 2 (2 which is the last index item) inside the Swiper function and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried another method where I just made the index: 2 (2 which is the last index item) inside the Swiper function and it worked. Now the pagination starts from right to left.

```
child: Swiper(
                        onIndexChanged: (int index) => activeIndex = index,
                        index: 2, //In my case 2 is the last item/index in the list.
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final image = letterVowelsImages[index];
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              image,
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        indicatorLayout: PageIndicatorLayout.COLOR,
                        autoplay: false,
                        itemCount: letterVowelsImages.length,
                        pagination: const SwiperPagination(
                          builder: DotSwiperPaginationBuilder(
                            color: Colors.black38,
                            activeColor: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        control: const SwiperControl(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
```